# ASP.NET GridView, enabling/disabling Next-Previous-First-Last buttons on paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have aspx page with master page which contains a grid-view control inside an update panel. I have implemented custom paging using . My pager contains Next-Previous-First-Last buttons. I want to enable/disable the buttons based on the page index change. I have written this enable/disable code in code behind C#. The code executes but when the grid-view is rendered in the browser it doesn't take the enable/disable and CSS properties set from the code behind.
I have come across similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933859/asp-net-gridview-enabling-disabling-buttons-after-paging) in SO but even though it has been marked as an answer if we look at the last comments by the person asking the question the solution doesn't seem to work for him too.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="AdministracionPerfilesIdxScriptMgr" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="AdministracionPerfilesIdxUpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" PageSize="6" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="tbl-data" OnSorting="grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx_PageIndexChanging"     OnRowDeleting="grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx_RowDeleting">
   <PagerTemplate>
       <ul class="jqGrid-pagination floatRight">
                                <li>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnFirstPage" runat="server" ToolTip="Primera"
                                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First"/>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPrevPage" runat="server" ToolTip="Anterior"
                                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev"/>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPageCounter" runat="server" CssClass="referencia">
                                        PÁGINA <%=grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageIndex + 1%> DE <%=grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageCount%>
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnNextPage" runat="server" ToolTip="Siguiente"
                                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnLastPage" runat="server" ToolTip="Última"
                                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </PagerTemplate>
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="alignCenter">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdButton" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:SelectSingleRadiobutton(this.id)" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="IDPerfil" HeaderText="PERFIL ID" SortExpression="IDPerfil" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="NOMBRE" SortExpression="Nombre" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Descripcion" HeaderText="DESCRIPCIÓN" SortExpression="Descripcion" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tipo" HeaderText="TIPO" SortExpression="Tipo" />
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="btn-icon">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDeleteGridRow" runat="server" CssClass="naranjo eliminar" 
                                         OnClientClick="return isRadioBtnSelected(this)" CommandName="Delete"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                         <EmptyDataTemplate>No Record Available</EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is my code behind code for paging - enable/disable:

```
 protected void grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        if (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageIndex == 0)
        {
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnFirstPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = false;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnFirstPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "first disabled";
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnPrevPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = false;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnPrevPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "prev disabled";

            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnNextPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnNextPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "next";
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnLastPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnLastPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "last";
        }
        else if ((grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageIndex > 0) & 
            ((grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageIndex + 1) != grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageCount))
        {
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnFirstPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnFirstPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "first";
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnPrevPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnPrevPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "prev";

            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnNextPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnNextPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "next";
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnLastPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnLastPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "last";
        }
        else if((grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageIndex > 0) & 
            ((grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageIndex + 1) == grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.PageCount))
        {
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnFirstPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnFirstPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "first";
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnPrevPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = true;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnPrevPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "prev";

            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnNextPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = false;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnNextPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "next disabled";
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnLastPage") as ImageButton).Enabled = false;
            (grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("imgBtnLastPage") as ImageButton).CssClass = "last disabled";
        }

        DataView dataView = Getdata();
        grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.DataSource = dataView;
        grdVwAdministracionPerfilesIdx.DataBind();
    }
```

**Please note that I don't have any problem in paging or grid-view. I only have problem enabling disabling the pager buttons on page index change.**

Comment: I am still stuck with this issue... any help is highly appretiated? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Finally I was able to resolve the issue. Problem was that I had written the code of changing the Pager button's CssClass and Enable/disable of those buttons in "PageIndexChanging" event. Those code should be written in "PageIndexChanged" event of gridview control for the effect to take place. "PageIndexChanged" event fires after "PageIndexChanging" event.